# New column which contains sum of everything except a given row in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data-wrangling

I have a mind numbing loop to write and your help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to summarise grouped data by excluding each row iteratively and summing the mean of the remaining group, then rejoining to form a new data frame.

So, for instance with this mockup data...

```
x <- c("A","A", "B", "B")
y <- c(10:13)

xy <- data.frame(x,y) %>% 
      group_by(x) %>% 
      mutate(index = row_number(x)) %>% 
      ungroup() 

xy$uniq_id<- with(xy, paste0(index, x))
```

[Heres an image of the mockup data frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqHsq.png)

For 1A I the output value would be 11 because without row 1A, the sum of y for group A is 11.
So, the value for 1B would be 13, and the value for 2B would be 12 ect.

Here is how I would do it manually for all the rows with index 1.

The full join is because I want the final output to show the original value of each row in addition to the summarised value for the group it belongs to

```
xynew <- xy %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(index != "1") %>% 
  mutate(sum_Sepal = sum(y))
  
  full_join(xy, xynew, by = "uniq_id")
```

My data frame has 38 groups with 1-70 rows per group so I cant do this manually!.

Your help in trying to writing a loop for this would be amazing.

Please let me know if you have any questions:)

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
xy %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(val = sum(y) - y)

  x         y index uniq_id   val
  <chr> <int> <int> <chr>   <int>
1 A        10     1 1A         11
2 A        11     2 2A         10
3 B        12     1 1B         13
4 B        13     2 2B         12
```

I am not sure you `full_join` expected output is correct, as it contradicts your written logic.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is helpful, however I think you may have mis-interpreted my question. I am trying to write a loop for this because the the value of y will change. My actuarial data frame has 38 groups with 1-70 rows per group so I cant do this manually. The full join is because I want the final output to show the original value of each row in addition to the summarised value for the group it belongs to.

Comment: I do not understand your question, in that case, despite rereading. It would be helpful if you could provide a dput for a larger sample input and expected output with more groups. An iterative full join of 70 groups as you did would have a few thousand columns, no?